# SQL UPDATE which continues even if some unique constraints are violated

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, try-catch, constraints

I am trying to sanitize my emails. One example is replacing '.con' emails with '.com'. This is what i have so far:

```
UPDATE users 
SET email = CONCAT(
SUBSTRING(email, 1, LENGTH(email)-3), 'com')
WHERE email like '%.con';
```

If the '.com' version of one single '.con' email already exists, this command fails. Is there a way to let it fail silently? The table is several million entries big, so adding a NOT EXISTS is not performing well enough

Comment: Adding a `not exists` is your only option. And what is "pretty big" and why do you think that is _not_ an option?

Comment: But what do you want to do if .com already exists - keep .con?!?

Comment: yes, keep .con

@a_horse_with_no_name: edited the numbers in. It was just en estimation by myself. But I will try the NOT EXISTS option now:
`... AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT email from users where email like CONCAT(SUBSTRING(users.email, 1, LENGTH(users.email)-3), 'com')
);`

Comment: "several millions" doesn't sound big actually (several _hundred_ millions would). If you have a _real_ performance problem, please read this: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions (or this: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) and then update your question.

Comment: BTW: the `NOT EXISTS(...)` construct will test *exactly the same condition* as the `UNIQUE` constraint, so it will not make the update slower. Only more successful.

Comment: The only alternative is to perform the update one row at a time in a PL/pgSQL loop with an exception handler, and it's going to be quite a bit slower than the `EXISTS` check...